# Hide navigationBar?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

1) **What is the difference between the three lines of code below?**

2) Also why does only the third line of code work if I'm returning to a viewController and the previous viewController has set the navigationBar to hidden through the same approach `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]` my assumption was that all three lines do the same thing?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

**Follow up:**

Why when I need to run this code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:incorrectAnswerNavigationBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It only works, working being setting the background image, otherwise the nav bar is just white.

if I have both these lines:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

If I leave out `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;` the space for the nav bar pops down but it's just white, there is no background image. If I have both lines it works and there is a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are functionally identical; the difference being one uses the dot notation while the other doesn't.  These two methods both fire `- (void) setHidden:(BOOL)hide` on the `navigationBar` property on the navigation controller.

Now the third one is a completely different method.  It's `- (void) setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hide` and is defined on `UINavigationController`.  The reason why this one works is this method is informing the navigation controller that you wish the navigation bar to be hidden while the first two manually set the navigation bar to be hidden.  The first two's changes are undone if `UINavigationController` calls any methods that modify the hidden property of the navigation bar, hence why the `setNavigationBarHidden:` method was created so you'd have a way of informing `UINavigationController` that no matter what it does, it should hide the navigation bar and not change it to be showing.

EDIT: For the second part of this question, you actually need to be calling `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` on `UINavigationController`.  That's the proper documented method for `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thank you taking time to tackle the question. I kind of undertand. Why would i use one over the other however?

Comment: With the first two, you can interchange them; it's a style choice.  However, for your purposes of hiding the navigation bar, you want to use the documented method that Apple has provided in order to hide the navigation bar as you have no assurances that an Apple method in UINavigationController will not undo your change if you use the first two.  The third one has the guarantee that it will hide as you're not manually messing with the navigationBar's hidden property.

Comment: Thanks! But this method [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: isn't working if I only call [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; and not also self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden I thought they changed the same property?

Comment: That is an entirely separate matter and question which you should make and post code for.  What exactly do you mean by not working?  You are making sure to call - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics on the navigation bar, yes (I didn't see you reference forBarMetrics in your comment)?

Comment: Sorry the full code is: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:incorrectAnswerNavigationBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; it only works (sets the background image, otherwise it's just white) if I have both these lines:    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

Comment: Do update your question above to fit this as your actual question if you're not opening a different question for it so it's easier for other answerers to see it :P

Comment: Ah, have you tried calling [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:]?  You don't appear to be calling the right method, which would explain the issue (set animated to NO if you don't want it animated).

Comment: That fixed it, but why? Why do I need the animated piece? Could you add this to your answer please and then I can mark it correct.

Comment: You need the animated part because that's the actual method call.  While navigationBarHidden is a property (and apparently calling the setter function for it didn't cause an issue), the proper method you're supposed to call to set the navigation bar to be hidden is - (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated .  You can find the method call in the UINavigationController documentation.