# Hide UINavigationBar in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm pretty much confused with hiding navigation bar.

In most of the UIViewController I'm using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

But some times UINavigationBar is not hidden or visible.

Instead, if I use:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

I can hide or show UINavigationBar.

What's the difference between above properties?

Comment: google it , you get answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270616/hide-navigationbar